# Bincount with indices

Tags: numpy

I am looking for an efficient way to compute the indices of the binnings of bincount as a ndarray.

To illustrate:

```
>>> x = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 2])
>>> b = np.bincount(x)
>>> b
[2 2 1]
```

I am now looking for an ndarray that represents the indices of the elements of each bin:

```
[0 3 1 2 4]
```

I am looking for a fast numpy solution that should not contain loops. Anyone knows how to implement this? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: you're looking for [argsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html)

Comment: Thanks, but argsort has a really bad complexity I fear because my x ndarray is extremely large. And sorting is not a requirement, so I hope that there is a better solution ;-)

Comment: I am also aware of [digitize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html). However this also uses argsort under the hood.

Comment: How else  could one get the required indicies without the equivalent of `argsort`?  `fast` numpy solutions are the result of doing the work in compiled code, rather than clever low-complexity algorithms.

Comment: `unique`  can return indices, but it too sorts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my array are more than 1mio elements in lengths, so the sort complexity is too large.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is a way without sorting: NumPy under the hood loops over the array and increments counters. One could just also store the indices while looping. This is achievable under the hood in linear time. But I am wondering if there is a NumPy operation that I can use.

Comment: Where's it going to store those indices?  `bincount` can store the counters in a fixed length `c` array (once it knows the maximum value, which probably requires a loop of its own).  If I had to find indices with plain Python I'd use a `collections.defaultdict(list)`, which of course uses lists, list append, and dict hashing.

Comment: In any case, `np.bincount` docs lists all the related functions.

Comment: The indices in your example are sorted, so I really don't get how you can sort something without sorting it. Can you explain how (conceptually) it could be done in linear time ?

Comment: The indices don't need to be sorted. In this example this was just by chance ;-) Conceptually, one could loop over the array and build indices lists for each element. Then in the end concatenate all those lists. This all can be done in linear time. While it's possible to implement this in Python, I am looking for something in pure numpy